# @RequestMapping cannot be resolved to a type - Only for @Controller and not for @RestController

Tags: java, spring-boot, import, spring-tool-suite, request-mapping

We are starting a (`Spring Starter Project`)project from the scratch. When we created a class (first and only) in our `controller` annotated with `@Controller` and tried to add `@RequestMapping` for a method, it gave error saying `@RequestMapping` cannot be imported.

Now when we gave `@RestController`, `@RequestMapping` was properly imported and we again tried to annotate with `@Controller` to see whether the import issue is still coming, nothing happened. Which means when annotated with `@RestController` it is imported and when first time when annotated with @Controller it won't be imported. Why is that?

**With Controller (first time)**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Controller
public class DashBoardController {

    @RequestMapping  // CTE - RequestMapping cannot be resolved to a type
    public String defaultGreeting() {
        return "Good day!!";
    }
}
```

**With RestController**

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class DashBoardController {

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String defaultGreeting() {
        return "Good day!!";
    }
}
```

So after using `RestController` the `RequestMapping` can be easily imported, then if we try removing the import statements and modify it to `Controller` the `RequestMapping` can't be imported.

Comment: can you share the error message you are getting because we are using '@RequestMapping' interchangeably with '@Controller' and '@RestController' without any issues?

Comment: Please add some sample code to identify the problems.. @Arun

Comment: @Raghvendra Garg its simple, like if you try to import some Class without its jars the eclipse will give error saying cannot be imported. The annotation is not even coming in the suggestion

Comment: You can always import any annotation. This is resolved at compile-time. Spring Boot comes only into play at run-time. So please show add some code and add the specific error message. *...cannot be imported* is not specific enough to help you.

Comment: can you share the spring-boot version you are using?

Comment: If the code is what you are using then obviously this won't work as you don't have an import for the `RequestMapping`... You replace the `RequestMapping` import with the `Controller` import.

Comment: Yeah @M. Deinum, that's the problem the import is not there and it is not even suggested by `STS` and if I write it manually it gives compile time error. I just wanted to know why the suggestion/import comes only for `@RequestMapping`

Comment: I would indeed wipe the local maven repo under ~/.m2/ to see if that solves the issue. If not, please create a sample project and create an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues with the sample project and exact steps how to reproduce this, including the version of STS that you use.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused when there is some missing dependency in .m2, try deleting it and again download the packages. also, check if you don't have any compatibility issue in versions
it has solved the issue for me.